# difference between ParseException and TokenManagerError (javaCC)

Tags: parsing, javacc, parseexception

What is the difference between ParseException and TokenManagerError?
Topic: javaCC, generate parser, error message
An example to explain would be good.

Tries to read in literature or error message, googel, chat, found nothing at least

Comment: There isn't that much documentation out there, but you can guess that TokenMgrError is about problems in the lexical analysis, and ParseException about syntactical analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A TokenManagerError is thrown when the input sequences of characters can not be turned into a sequence of Tokens -- i.e., when lexical analysis fails.

A ParseException occurs when the input sequence of tokens can't be matched -- i.e., when parsing fails.

See the FAQ for advice on how and why to avoid TokenManagerErrors.